# $\lim_{t\to 0^+}u(t) u'(t)$ for a function $u \in C^1(0,1)$ with $u(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to know if $\exists$ $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0^+}u(t) u'(t)$ for a function $u \in C^1(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$ with $u(0)=0$. If $u \in C^1[0,1),$ it's trivial. I'm interested in the case $u \not \in C^1[0,1).$ For example, if $u(t)=t^{\frac{1}{2}},$ then $u'(t)=\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$ Consequently $u(t) u'(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $t \in (0,\infty),$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+}u(t) u'(t)=\frac{1}{2}.$

Are there any general result for this question? [**No general result : see below user296602 comment**]

If there is no result for general functions, we may think

(1) $u$ is a concave function on $[0,1].$ [**It's false: see below G.Sassatelli comment**]

Or

(2)**$u=u(t)$ is a solution to a singular differential equation**, e,g., $u$ is as solution to problem $u''+h(t)f(u)=0,~t \in (0,1)$ with $u(0)=u(1)=0$, where $h \not \in L^1(0,1)$ and $|f(u)|\le C|u|$ for $u \in \mathbb{R}.$

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment for this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, such a limit does not generally exist; take a function which is highly oscillatory, such as $x \sin x^{-2}$. Then the expression is

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} (x \sin x^{-2}) \cdot (\sin x^{-2} + x \cos x^{-2} \cdot (-2x^{-3}))$$ which fails to exist because of the final term.

Comment: So basically you are asking which conditions on (continuous et cetera) $u$ guarantee that $u^2$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: By the way, along the lines of your remark, $u(x)=x^{\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha<1/2$ is concave, yet $\lim_{x\to 0^+} u'(x)u(x)=+\infty$. Of course, since concavity implies weakly decreasing derivative, this is the only possible obstruction.